# Microphone doesn't work when adapter is plugged in anymore

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone

A few days ago the microphone on my headset had stopped working, when I try to use it via the adapter. It was working fine, then suddenly it stopped detecting my voice when I turned it on the next day. It can still receive audio fine. Pulseaudio does detect the microphone, but the bar showing the input seems to stay at the lowest level [as seen in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGXRk.png).

When I try to connect with the cable, the microphone does work, but has a loud hum in the background.

In case you need to know, I use Xubuntu 20.04.
Thank for the help!

Comment: What is "the adapter"? How does it connect to your computer, and how does it connect to your headset.  What headset are you using?

Comment: It's a USB wireless adapter. You plug it in the computers USB port and it detects the headset. I am using the Mpow BH470A headset

Comment: More info may be needed to help you. I just looked up the device and it says it uses the same wireless frequency as WiFi 2.4. Has something changed on you system?